# In Python what is the "main section which calls the functions"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the assignment:

> Write a function called nine_lines that uses the function three_lines
>   (provided below) to print a total of nine lines.
>
> Now add a function named clear_screen that uses a combination of the
>   functions nine_lines, three_lines, and new_line (provided below) to
>   print a total of twenty-five lines. The last line of your program
>   should call the function clear_screen.
>
> The  function three_lines and new_line are defined below so that you
>   can see nested function calls. Also, to make counting “blank” lines
>   visually easier, the print command inside new_line will print a dot at
>   the beginning of the line:
>
> ```
> def new_line():
>     print('.')
>
> def three_lines():
>     new_line()
>     new_line()
>     new_line()
> ```
>
> Does the assignment implement new_line, three_lines, nine_lines, and
>   clear_screen functions, as well as a main section of the program which
>   calls the functions? Does the assignment demonstrate the use of nested
>   function calls?

Below is my submission:

```
def new_line():
    print ('.')

def three_lines():
    new_line()
    new_line()
    new_line()

def nine_lines():
    three_lines()
    three_lines()
    three_lines()

#use of nested functions here. They are combined to get the result of 25 lines.
def clear_screen():
    nine_lines()
    nine_lines()
    three_lines()
    three_lines()
    new_line()

#Declaring message1, message2, message3 for a later use
message1 = '9 lines successfully printed'
message2 = 'Calling clearScreen() to print 25 lines'
message3 = "25 lines successfully printed"


# Main section of the program which calls the functions "nine_lines" and "clearScreen", 

def main():   
    print(nine_lines(), message1)
    print(message2)
    clear_screen()
    print(message3)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Below is the solution submitted by the instructor:

```
# define a function to print one blank line
def new_line():
    print('.')

# define a function to print 3 blank lines
def three_lines():
    new_line()
    new_line()
    new_line()

# define a function to print 9 blank lines
def nine_lines():
    three_lines()
    three_lines()
    three_lines()

# define a funciton to print 25 blank lines
def clear_screen():
    nine_lines()
    nine_lines()
    three_lines()
    three_lines()
    new_line()

# Print nine lines to console
print("Printing nine lines")
nine_lines()
# Print 25 lines to console
print("Calling clearScreen()")
clear_screen()
```

I am wondering where is the main section of the program that calls the functions in the code submitted as "solution" because I was thinking the following lines of code was the main section of a Python program:

```
def main():   

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: You *can* use `if __name__ == "__main__":` to guard a call to an entry point function, and that function *can* be named `main`, but neither is *required*. In the instructor's solution, the section of the code starting with the call to `new_line()` *is* their *"main section of the program which calls the functions"*.

Comment: thanks jonrsharpe, I didn't noticed that was not required and I thought the main function was  the "def main()" section of the program. What do you think about the pedagogical approach here?

Comment: It's good practice to use `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`, since it allows you to import your functions of this file into another file, without executing all your top-level code (except defining the functions). Instead it requires an explicit call to `yourfile.main()`.

Comment: @Nico It's hard to say. If it is a beginners class, then perhaps it confuses less to keep it simple without main-functions etc.

Comment: @Jeppe Thank you so much